# Why "react-detector" nor "Show me the React!" (reactjs) Chrome extensions doesn't work on facebook.com

Tags: reactjs

I'm using "react-detector" and "Show me the React!" (2 reactjs Chrome extension detectors) but they don't detect the react javascript library on facebook.com.
Why ?

Answer (score 2):

Both these extension work by looking for the `data-reactid` attributes that React places on DOM elements that it creates (see [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-detector/blob/54cf8a606eec6d47fd1e05d1c7a7cde73cba2603/content-script.js#L2) and [here](https://github.com/cymen/show-me-the-react/blob/ff2310b7aeb5ff848367a5cde6952f400953b160/js/background.js#L6)). However, starting with React 0.15 (which has not been published yet), `data-reactid` is not added to the DOM in most (or perhaps all) cases.

You can build React from master and take a look at the difference; here's a screenshot comparing 0.14.5's output and master's output:

[image: Screenshot]

The output on the right contains a new `data-reactroot` attribute in place of the old `data-reactid=".0"`, but otherwise contains no special React attributes.

Facebook commonly runs React from master on their site to get new features and to test things out long before it gets published to an official version, so it's very likely they're running a version that supports this new feature.

Comment: I am learning React. How should i go in production? should i set data-reactid manually?. I guess the benefit will be to see my component with react-detector. But does it really matter?